# Creating new site columns or renaming existing ones,, which approach I should follow

Tags: list, development, content-type, administration, site-column

I have a team site and I have created a new Issue Tracking lists inside it. Then I went to the Issue content type I found these columns defined by default:-
Currently I need some of these and I need others.
For example I need the following:-

[image]

1. I want to have a column named “Estimated Resolution Date”, so should I just rename the available “Due Date” or create a new site column for this?
2. I want to have a column named “Status” and not the available “Issue Status“. So should I add the existing “Status ” site column to my content type ? or create a new list 
   column named “Status”?
3. Also I need a lookup filed named “Office Location” , so should I create a new site column for this ? or rename any of the available lookups site columns?
4. If I rename a site column inside the Issue content type, will it change the original site column name ? or it will only change the column name inside this list?
5. Finally why the are the Created, Modified, etc columns that are available for the list are not part of the Issue content type itself?

Thanks in advance for any help?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a new content type that inherits from the issue content type. You could then remove and use the fields you need from issue content type. The created modified fields are system fields. These are usually defined in the base type item.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms472236(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: but even if i create a new content type still my original questions of either Creating new site columns or renaming existing ones are valid ? can u advice ?

Comment: If you create a content type that inherits from issue content type and then you rename the Due Date column it will only affect the inherited content type and not the base content type Issue. I hope I answered that correctly

Comment: But what if someone edit the "Due Date" site column itself and rename it to another name ,, then all the content types  will be affected... so the confusion comes from should we rename the site column even inside the content types ? or if we need specific name that is not already avilable to just create a new site column named "Estimated Resolution Date" ??

Comment: Yes only the content types that have been changed. So if you created a new content type called inheritedIssue and changed the duedate to teminationdate it will only affect the inheritedIssue content type and not the Issue content type. Simply inherit from the content types that sharepoint provides if you want to customize them and don't modify the originals.

Comment: Me personally I prefer to create new site columns for my new content types.

Comment: yes but what if someone by mistake went to to the Due Date site column and update its name, then the teminationdate will get overridden ,,,, so it is better to create a new site column and name it "teminationdate" ?? is this correct ?

Comment: Yeah in that specific scenario but you should have more control over the changes you apply to the columns. even if you created a new site column and someone renames it the same will happen regardless.

Comment: yes but at least the reason to rename the new site columns will be less, also if there is a plan to rename "Estimated Resolution Date" to another name then most probably that we want the rename to affect all the available lists,,, because the site column is originally named "Estimated Resolution Date", unlike having its original name as "Due Date" so the reasons to rename it will be more and the possibility for a wrong re-name will happen,, does this make sense ?

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I can see your reasoning. I would suggest creating new columns then

Answer (score 0):

You can existing site column using powershell:

```
$site = Get-SPSite -Identity "http://serverName:4001/"
$web = $site.RootWeb 
$field=$web.Fields["Custom Site Column"]
$field.Type= "Choice"
$field.Update($true)
$web.Dispose()
$site.Dispose()
```

But i think is the good practice as Joseph mention above is to create a content type which inherits from the issue content type

Comment: but my original questions is not about how to create new site columns or renaming them,,, I am asking about the best approach to follow, now if i create a new content type,, still i have to make a decision on weather to rename existing site columns or to create new ones.....